# Change UITableViewStyle to Plain programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have taken tableView. I want to change tableView style to Plain but compiler says it's only get property.

```
datesTableView.style = UITableViewStyle.Plain
```

error: 'style' is a get-only property.

How can I do it programmatically?

Comment: Why not in Interface Builder?

Comment: I am adding this tableView as a modalView on button action. So I have to create this tableView after button is tapped.

Comment: Then you have to initialize the tableview using `init(frame frame: CGRect,  style style: UITableViewStyle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've resolved it with this code:

```
let datesTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)
```

Comment: That's creating a new instante of UITableView, not changing it.

Comment: You cannot change the tableView style once set. So the only way is set the style  during initialisation.

Answer (score 3):

`style` is a readonly property of `UITableView`.

That means you can initialize a table as `grouped` or `plane`, but you cannot change the style afterwards.

Comment: Man, `readonly` for this variable means Nothing because in swift it is declared as `open var style: UITableView.Style { get }` which means you can't set it directly in `UITableView` but you can subclass `UITableView` and create a custom setter for it. I didn't try how it works but anyways it is possible to set other value

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the table style once it's initialised. You'd have to create a new `UITableView` instance with a different style.